# How do I copy or import Oracle schemas between two different databases on different servers?

Tags: oracle

What is the best way to copy schema from one user/instance/server:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@deeb02:1535:DH, user pov
```

to another user/instance/server

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.456.789.123:1523:orcl, user vrs_development
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similarly, if you're using Oracle 10g+, you should be able to make this work with Data Pump:

```
expdp user1/pass1@db1 directory=dp_out schemas=user1 dumpfile=user1.dmp logfile=user1.log
```

And to import:

```
impdp user2/pass2@db2 directory=dp_out remap_schema=user1:user2 dumpfile=user1.dmp logfile=user2.log
```

Comment: There was one issue for me. It was necessary to setup dp_out. I have done it in following way:
grant create any directory to SCHEMA_NAME; 
create directory DP_OUT as 'PATH_TO_DIR';

Answer (score 5):

Use oracle `exp` utility to take a dump of the schema from the first database

```
exp user1/pass1@db1 owner=user1 file=user1.dmp log=user1.log
```

Then use `imp` utility to populate the other schema in the other datbase

```
imp user2/pass2@db2 fromuser=user1 touser=user2 file=user1.dmp log=user2.log
```

Comment: e.g.: exp hr/hr@myHostName:1521 owner=hr file=hr.dmp log=hrdump.log then imp myDb/myPass@myHostName:1521 full=y file=hr.dmp log=mydump.log

Answer (score 0):

you can directly copy schema via network (without moving files from one server to another) using datapump parameter NETWORK LINK as described here:

http://vishwanath-dbahelp.blogspot.com/2011/09/network-link-in-datapump.html

for example:

```
impdp -userid user/pass@destination_server LOGFILE=log.txt NETWORK_LINK=dblink_from_dest_to_source SCHEMAS=schema1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR
```

check that directory DATA_PUMP_DIR exists in

```
select *
from dba_directories
```

and points to correct place in destination_server file system.