# How do I copy or import Oracle schemas between two different databases on same servers?

Tags: import, oracle11g, export, database-administration

I am using oracle 11gr2 server. 
It is having two Database instances.

- DBSB1
- DBSB2

Both are having similar character set and single byte instances. 
We are dropping a instance DBSB2. We would like to move few of its Schemas into DBSB1.
What are the possible ways to do that?

Comment: tried exp / imp or expdp?

Comment: No, but as they are located in same server. am expecting a better and easier approach.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451219/how-do-i-copy-or-import-oracle-schemas-between-two-different-databases-on-differ

Comment: Thanks Satya, Even if they are located in same machine still we should do logical export and import, and there is no other way do handle this?

Comment: well you can write a batch file/shell script which when run will extract each object of each schema and then push it to the new schema. But that will be fairly long, and more like re-inventing the wheel , when you already have tailormade solutions from Oracle itself.