# Change Oracle Apex apps to another Database on same system

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

Good Day. I have a situation which I am unsure of how to solve. I have searched numerous places and found nothing concrete.

The scenario:
I have 3 Oracle Apex 5 applications running on a single server using Oracle Express locally in order to run the app. I however had to go to Oracle 12c which is installed as a separate instance on the same server and it's listener is now listening on `1522` where XE is still listening on `1521`.

I am needing to find a way to export the schema, tables, apps etc. into 12C from XE, then simply configure the apps to connect to the 12C instance and no longer on XE. I can then remove XE completely.

I know I am supposed to post what I have tried, but simply have no code, I have tried to do a export DDL but the script does not seem to carry the Schema data at all.

Question: How can I migrate everything on the XE instance to the 12C instance without breaking either instances.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have done this once. First I copied the schema (or schmas) from the old database to the new one. Then I did an Apex install (or rather upgrade) on the new database. Then I imported the Apex App into Apex on the new database.

Comment: @sers Thank you. What was the method you used to copy the schema's to the new DB?

Comment: don't really remember. But you should have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451219/how-do-i-copy-or-import-oracle-schemas-between-two-different-databases-on-differ
Or here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2369986?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thank you @sers I will have a look at the link. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps: data(base) migration & (Apex) application migration.

The simplest way to move data is to perform export and import. Although you can use the *original* EXP and IMP utilities, consider using modern Data Pump Export and Import.

- EXP and IMP are somewhat simpler; export (DMP) file is created on your disk
- Data Pump requires you to create an Oracle directory (object) which points to a directory on the disk. As it is XE installed on your computer, no problem if it is, for example, C:\Temp
- syntax is very similar in both cases, especially if there's nothing *fancy* in your data

The second step is application migration; you should first install Apex in the new Oracle 12c. Make sure it is up and running (create a workspace, assign a schema (you've just imported) to it, create a developer).

Then export the Apex application(s) - if there are only a few of them, a simple way is to do export from the application itself (you'll see the "Export/Import" button in the "main" application page within the App. Builder). Follow the wizard. The result will be a plain textual (.SQL) file.

In Apex on 12c, revert the process - do the Import by navigating to previously exported .SQL file, follow the wizard once again. Once the import is finished, you should be able to run the application.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will follow the steps and see where I get with this.

Comment: All done, it was no so painful after all, installed 12c, installed apex on it, copied the workspaces from internal to 12c and  imported/exported views, tables and db links.. Working great. Think I can actually build an automation tool for this to be honest.. will make it much easier.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you made it.